# Need help understanding section of code

Tags: python

I wrote a piece of code, it was marked by an auto machine-bot.

We are not allowed to question this bot, its "100% correct".

I got 90%. Professor wont go over it, and we are "meant to" pay a higher year student to help us if we have troubles, because this is a basic level course.

Here is the code:

```
def something(placeholder):
    """
    append intengers
    """
    siba = list()
    try:
        for items in placeholder:
            if int(items):
                siba.append(int(items))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return siba


placeholder = ["123", "+142", "-39", "GRTG356", "x", "12-3", "123+"]
print(something(placeholder))
```

Can anyone tell me what I could have probably done to get 100%? This was the only section of code I got marked "0" for. I still get the same answer, its just the method is wrong.

Comment: Is there any more output of this bot? It is hard to tell what it is complaining about if we don't know what it looks for.

Comment: Should the exception handling be inside the loop, not outside?

Comment: what was the goal of the code?

Comment: So what is the question? We are supposed to guess what those % are supposed to mean and fix it for you? `int(items)` is incorrect check and not needed.

Comment: What output are you expecting? It works. Output is `[123, 142, -39]` which is expected

Comment: The bot literally "marks an area red" if its wrong. The problem is I got the "correct answer", but this area of code is "wrong".

Sorry, they use a bot to mark everyone's scores, I cant say much more than that cause even I cant ask why its wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error handling will currently return the list if a value inside can't be converted to a int. it should instead go to the next item.

```
def something(placeholder):
    """
    append intengers
    """
    siba = list()
    for items in placeholder:
        try:
            siba.append(int(items))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return siba
```

If I supply your original code with `["123", "+142", "-39", "GRTG356", "x", '1', "12-3", "123+", '572']` it would return `["123", "+142", "-39"]` when it should instead return `[123, 142, -39, 1, 572]`

Comment: Are you the bot? :) Just to clarify for OP: If an exception occurred in their code, the loop will terminate. Your solution works because it'll continue to the next element on error.

Comment: No but the return list would be incomplete if the input data were slightly different. Therefore I assume that this was the issue.

Comment: Thank you @MarounMaroun I now understand it and what I did wrong!